# Automatically filling area surrounded by other polygons?

Tags: polygon, qgis-3, digitizing

I want to fill the gap with a polygon automatically. It is surrounded by other polygons but the part inside the yellow circle is another shapefile. The gap is not made by adding a ring.

Or is my only choice to manually digitize?

[image: example1]

[image: example2]

Comment: Have you looked into the Difference/Symmetrical Difference geoprocessing tools (one layer being the 'background' shapefile, and one layer being the 'foreground' shapefile)

Comment: Didn't even think of that somehow. I'll check if it works.